# HTML: tbody columns first look the order of thead columns and then display

Tags: html, css

I have some problem using **HTML tables**.

Below I have a table structure.

```
<table>
    <caption>Movie Details</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th axis="m" header="movie">Movie Name</th>
            <th axis="g" header="genre"> Genre</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- note: rows generates dynamically using loop -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td axis="m">Aanjana Anjani</td>
            <td axis="g">Romance</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td axis="m">Bodyguard</td>
            <td axis="g">Romance</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td axis="m">Gajini</td>
            <td axis="g">Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td axis="m">Singham</td>
            <td axis="g">Action</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Currently this table is **sorted by movie name**, now

> Is there any way that, if I swap the column in `<thead>` then `<tbody>`,
>   data is swapped automatically (means `tbody` looking to `thead` and then
>   display ) using only HTML?

means if I change the column order ( `genre` is first column now),

```
<th axis="g" header="genre"> Genre</th>
<th axis="m" header="movie">Movie Name</th>
```

then column of each row of `<tbody>` should be changed.

I think the `axis` and `headers` attributes may be helpful for this but not getting the exact.

[Reference for `axis` in `headers`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#multi-dimension).

Comment: You are being downvoted because you ask a question with a scope so narrow that you should know it is not achievable. "Show me a green elephant, but don't use a bucket of paint" is not something we like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you're willing to consider (just a little) CSS. In the example below, you "switch columns" simply by swapping the names of the CSS classes. (that is, change `.right` to `.left`, and `.left` to `.right`). You don't have to make any changes to the HTML in the table itself.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .right {width:100px; float:right;}
   .left {width:100px; float:left;}
</style>

<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td width="250px">
            <div class="right">LEFT</div>
            <div class="left">RIGHT</div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td width="250px">
         <div class="right">L Data</div>
         <div class="left">R Data</div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "if i change the column order"?

You can only change the HTML structure in real time using JavaScript.

If you want to change it without JavaScript you then have to reload the page with a server side language like PHP which will sort the table and write the HTML code differently.

Anyway you choose, swapping only the `<thead>` content or replacing it is not enough. You still have to replace/change the content of the `<tbody>` also to see the items sorted in the new way.